# How to work with git submodules using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, git, bitbucket

I work with a big project, and I have Server and Client side, and from this 2 project I have one header view, and I don't want to copy paste.

So for this, I create **git submodules**, and I add into my project.

After addind i recived such message at git extention:

```
[submodule "headerpaneltest"]
path = headerpaneltest
url = https://bitbucket/testProject/headerpaneltest.git
```

I work in Visual Studio Pro 2017.

So in this folder **headerpaneltest** I have file **_HeaderPanel.cshtml** which I want to fetch from submodule and use into my current project.

How I can do this?

Comment: So do you want only 1 file from your submodule?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk For this moment yes

Comment: So why add the whole repo as submodule?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk because now i test this, at future i will have HTML files, CSS and JS which some how i want to fetch from submodules

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk but i cant found some info how to do it

Comment: Where you add the submodule you specify a path in your repo where the second repo files (the submodules files) will be cloned/fetched there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195106/discussion-between-qunz666-and-shayki-abramczyk).